# Is it possible to draw a closed 8-segment broken line that intersects each segment of itself exactly once?

Tags: geometry

> Is it possible to draw a closed 8-segment broken line that intersects each
>   segment of itself exactly once?

Problem is from the *Mathematical Circles* book.

Comment: @clathratus In the usual phrasing of this problem, the self-intersections must be in the interior of each segment, so an octagon wouldn't count.

Answer (score 7):

Yes!  The construction is tricky.  The key to finding it is to note that all intersections come in pairs, so if side A intersects side B, then B intersects A.  After this, you would try to "map out" a bunch of different ways to pair up the sides.  After some observations (e.g. two consecutive sides can't intersect, and trying to pair up two sides that have one side between them won't work either), we can eventually find a pairing that works, and experimentation gets us the following:

> [image: yay]